# Retrofit - Append text to the end of end point after queries inserted

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to produce the end point like `/api/method?page=1.json` but the problem is queries will be inserted at the end just like `/api/method.json?page=1`.

```
// from my service
@GET("method.json")
Call<Void> method(@Query("page") int page);

// building retrofit
new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(httpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

**Update/** Following works but I @Blackbelt answer is the best one.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    request = request.newBuilder().url(request.url().toString().concat(".json")).build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to produce the end point like /api/method?page=1.json

why. Without the `.json` it looks better and you somehow hide the information that the response is a `json` object.

```
but the problem is queries will be inserted at the end just like /api/method.json?page=1.
```

That's the expected behaviour. As you saw it appends what you are providing as parameter. So you could change from

```
Call<Void> method(@Query("page") int page);
```

to

```
Call<Void> method(@Query("page") String page);
```

and then you call it like

```
method(String.valueOf(page).concat(".json"));
```

Comment: It is an ugly solution I think. Why I'm doing this is because of CakePHP which returns result as a JSON. Is there another solution? Is it possible to change URL before using inside of a callback?

Comment: You could use an interceptor, but I would avoid that and keep it simple

Comment: Can you provide me an interceptor for this case?

Comment: I updated my question with an interceptor. Can you rewrite it to work correctly please? thanks.

Comment: it looks ok.. what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to change like

```
@GET("method.json")
Call<Void> method(@Query("page") String page);
```

and pass value like method("1.json")

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like,

```
@GET("method?page={page}.json")
Call<Void> method(@Path("page") int page);
```

Comment: It helps but it's an ugly solution. `@Query` have to be used.